# C#. Search array of strings for longest element

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I want to know how I can get out everyone of the the longest persons if there are several with the same length?

If only one person is the longest, then it works fine and the longest person with it´s name will show in MessageBox. But if there are more than one who are the longest, this code will not work...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] längdArray = new int[5];
    string[] namnArray = new string[5];
    int namn = 0;
    int längd = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnVisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int längst = 0;
        int längdvärdet = 0;
        int längdindex = 0;

        string name = textBox1.Text;
        namnArray[namn] = name;
        namn = namn + 1;

        textBox1.Clear();

        int centimeter = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        längdArray[längd] = centimeter;
        längd++;

        textBox2.Clear();

        listBox1.Items.Add(name + " " + centimeter + " centimeter ");

        if (längd == 5)
        {
            btnVisa.Enabled = false;

            foreach (int antalLängder in längdArray)
            {
                if (antalLängder > längst)
                {
                    längst = antalLängder;
                    längdvärdet = längdindex;

                }
                längdindex++;


            }
            string test = namnArray[längdvärdet]

            MessageBox.Show(" Längsta person är " + test  + " som är " + längst + " centimeter lång ");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define behavior you want your app to present when there is more than one person. Should all display, or any one, or other? Try to use object constructions, it's easier to operate on them. C# is an object-oriented language. Put name and length in one structure then use LINQ.